# How to rollback a transaction using dapper

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I have this:

```
            using (var con= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlcon"].ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                  // many transactions
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    con.BeginTransaction().Rollback();
                }
            }
```

Will this work is my question.. I know another method is to make a transaction then open it then rollback.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dapper extends the DbConnection so there is no problem in using the standard Transaction object

```
using (var con= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlcon"].ConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var ts = con.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
           // many db action where you pass the transaction 
           // object like here
           string text = "INSERT INTO .....";
           var pms = new {p1name=pvalue, p2name, pvalu2};
           var result = cmd.Execute(sql, pms, transaction:ts);
           .....
           ts.Commit(); // Final commit...
       }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // No rollback needed if you don't call Complete.
        // A rollback is automatic exiting from the using block
        // con.BeginTransaction();
    }
}
```

You could simplify a bit the code above using a [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) variable in a using block at the same level of the using block of the SqlConnection

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
using (var con= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlcon"].ConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
       // many actions as above....
       ......
       scope.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // No rollback needed if you don't call Complete.
        // A rollback is automatic exiting from the using block
        // TransactioScope
    }
}
```

But this is a bit more "heavy" on the system resources. So if you don't really need the added benefits of TransactionScope you can just use the normal transaction object and perhaps add a method where you return the connection already opened to avoid some lines of code

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper note that all of the dapper operations accept an ado.net transaction as an optional parameter; if you use ado.net transactions, be sure to include it in your calls

Comment: @Steve Wouldn't the standard ado.net transaction lightweight than the ambient transaction and if multiple connections are open in the ambient transaction, it will be promoted to the Distributed transaction